# How do I make the fist value in each sublist that is part of a big list into a process id?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, openpyxl, scheduler

How do I make the fist value in each sublist that is part of a big list into a process id?

I've extracted data from a .xlsx file like this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename=r"C:\Users\sample.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active


output = []
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                           max_row=21,
                           min_col=1,
                           max_col=4,
                           values_only=True):
    listtest = []
    for cell in row:
        listtest.append(str(cell))

    output.append(listtest)
```

Giving me an output like this:

> [[Process ID, Arrival Time, Burst Load, Priority]]
>
> [['1', '1', '8', '2'], ['2', '2', '9', '4'], ..., ['20', '90', '4', '14']]

What I want is to change out the static values for Process ID, Arrival Time, Burst Load, Priority and use the values I've extracted from .xlsx.

```
def findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt):
    wt[0] = 0
    # calculating waiting time
    for i in range(1, n):
        wt[i] = bt[i - 1] + wt[i - 1]

def findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat):
    # calculating turnaround
    for i in range(n):
        tat[i] = bt[i] + wt[i]

def findavgTime(processes, n, bt):
    wt = [0] * n
    tat = [0] * n
    total_wt = 0
    total_tat = 0

    # Function to find waiting time of all processes
    findWaitingTime(processes, n, bt, wt)

    # Function to find turn around time for all processes
    findTurnAroundTime(processes, n, bt, wt, tat)

    # Display processes along with all details
    print("Processes Burst time " +
          " Waiting time " +
          " Turn around time")

    # Calculate total waiting time and total turn around time
    for i in range(n):
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i]
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i]
        print(" " + str(i + 1) + "\t\t" +
              str(bt[i]) + "\t " +
              str(wt[i]) + "\t\t " +
              str(tat[i]))

    print("Average waiting time = " +
          str(total_wt / n))
    print("Average turn around time = " +
          str(total_tat / n))


# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # process id's
    processes = [1, 2, 3]
    n = len(processes)

    # Burst time of all processes
    burst_time = [10, 5, 8]

    findavgTime(processes, n, burst_time)
```

To get this output:

> Processes, Burst time, Waiting time, Turn around time
>
> 1, 1, 8, 2
>
> 2, 2, 9, 4
>
> 3, 2, 5, 5
>
> 4, 3, 5, 2
>
> 5, 6, 14, 7
>
> Average waiting time = 8.333333333333334
>
> Average turn around time = 16.0

I tried this way:

```
listtest = []
for cell in row:
    listtest.append(str(cell))
    new_list = []
    for item in output:
        new_list.append(item[0])

output.append(listtest)
```

But this only puts them into a new list which I guess has no link with the rest of the sublists' values?

Would really appreciate any hints or examples here. Thanks! :D

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hello again :) see edit

Comment: I don't understand how what you have is different from what you want.

Comment: In the driver code (processes = [1, 2, 3]) these are static numbers. I want them to be changed out with only the first value in each sublist in my big list of lists.

Comment: What if it was processes=[5, 9, 11]? Do you then need only the 1st values from the 5th 9th and 11th sub-lists?

Comment: processes = [1 (1, 1, 8, 2), 2 (2, 2, 9, 4), 3 (3, 2, 5, 5), 4 (4, 3, 5, 2), 5 (5, 6, 14, 7)]

Comment: No, in processes I want all the first values of each sublist, not just 1,2,3. So its basically processes = [1-20].

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try zip:

```
h = [
    ['Process ID', 'Arrival Time', 'Burst Load', 'Priority']
]

d = [
    ['1', '1', '8', '2'], 
    ['2', '2', '9', '4'], 
    ['2', '2', '9', '4'], 
    ['20', '90', '4', '14']
]

x = zip(h[0], d)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
('Process ID', ['1', '1', '8', '2'])
('Arrival Time', ['2', '2', '9', '4'])
('Burst Load', ['2', '2', '9', '4'])
('Priority', ['20', '90', '4', '14'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
processes = [output[0] for o in output]
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me errors, but only because of how my code has been written around having the static values. I'll try to write it over and then see. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: Read `output` as you did before. Don't change any of your previous code. Just include this answer in `__main__`. What errrors are you facing?

Comment: I'm trying to code a FIFO CPU Scheduler. I've managed to do so, but I've done it with static numbers for the simplicity. However, I need to rewrite the code to use the output now. If you want I can create a super detailed question with the entire block of code.

Comment: No need. Just include the output of, well, `output`

Comment: Oh, didn't see before refreshing. So I just put the output code into __main__?

Comment: That's where I presume you want to read your file so yes. Read your excel file with the first block of code you have to `output` and then add this line to get the `processes`